# Simple geometry question

Tags: geometry

In the picture below you can see a triangle were $AB$ is equal to $AC$, so if $AOB$ is $x$ I understand why the other ones are too. But why is $OBC$ is $2x$?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more context. I guess, this is still part of the hypothesis of the exercise.

Comment: Something is wrong here, they may not have to be $2x$ given that all the others are $x$ (for example pick $x=45$ degrees).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the two skinny triangles. Their missing third angles are each $180-2x$, adding up to $360-4x$.

So the unwritten angle of the fattish triangle is $4x$. That leaves $180-4x$ to be split between the two bottom angle, $90-2x$ to each. **Not** $2x$. Unless, of course, $x=22.5$, which it needn't be.

Or else, **better**,  look at the big triangle. At the top it has angle $2x$. Instead of $2x$ for the bottom angles, which is wrong, write $y$ and $y$.

Then $2x+2(x+y)=180$, giving $y=90-2x$.

**Remark:** The first solution was a typical instance of *angle-chasing*. We filled in all the angles, finally getting to the ones of interest. Nothing wrong with angle-chasing, it is pleasantly algorithmic. In the second solution, we went directly for the goal.

Comment: got it now, thanks! @André Nicolas

Comment: You are welcome. And thanks for the clear question, with clear diagram, and indication of work.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information you don't know that it is.  As long as $B$ and $C$ are symmetric with respect to $OA$, the angles $OBC$ and $OCB$ are equal but can have a range of values.  Think of them first at $9$ o'clock and $3$ o'clock.  Then $x=45^\circ$ and $OBC=OCD=0^\circ$.  If they approach 6 o'clock, $x$ approaches $0^\circ$ and $OBC=OCB$ approaches $90^\circ$